# Vue JS - Bind select option value to model inside v-for

Tags: vuejs2

I have a table populated with an array of objects (mappedMenus).

MappedMenus is a class that has a propery named "menuTypeId".

The possible values for this property "menuTypeId" are set in an array of MenuTypes objects, that have an "id" and a "name" property.

With these MenuTypes objects, I populate the *select* for each row.

The problem I´m having, is that I don´t know how to bind the "menuTypeId" property of every MappedMenu object to its *select* selected option.

As you can see in my code, I do a v-for in the  *tr* with my mappedMenus.

For every object, I have a row with a *select* with options.
The options are populated using another array named menuTypes.

Then I tried to bind the select with the MappedMenu object in the loop (e.menuTypeId) and then bind the value in the option.
I dont get any error with the following code, but I does not works either.

```
<table id="#divTable" class="uk-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Menu Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="e in mappedMenus">
            <td>
                <select class="uk-select" v-model="e.menuTypeId">
                    <option v-for="m in menuTypes" v-bind:value="e.menuTypeId">{{m.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var updateMenuVM = new Vue({
    el: '#divTable',
    data: {
        menuTypes: [{ id: 1, name: 'Principal' }, { id: 2, name: 'Dessert' }, { id: 3, name: 'Drink' }],
        mappedMenus: [{ menuName: 'Hamburger', menuTypeId: 1 }, { menuName: 'Ice Cream', menuTypeId: 2 }, { menuName: 'Sprite', menuTypeId: 3 }]
    }
</script>
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what should be the desired output.

Comment: @Andres Your code example isn't event complete...

Comment: I believe you were looking for this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-work-with-objects-as-select-option-values/45490 I hope it helps!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shouldn't you use something like `m.id` instead of `e.menuTypeId`? Because the `e.menuTypeId` is also a model.

I've also tested binding in `for` and it works fine.

```html
<select v-model="testVal">
    <option v-for="item in test" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
data() {
    return{
        test: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        testVal: null
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get custom key in value attribute?

Comment: How can be this method work for v-for? all others select box will be update its value same as the changed value. It will not work for the v-for.

Answer (score 3):

### Year 2022

The accepted answer is right but outdated. In every Vue iteration you need to
assign a unique key.

```html
<select v-model="testVal">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in test" 
      :value="item" 
      :key="index">
        {{item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

```js
data() {
    return{
        test: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        testVal: null
    }
}
```

If you have a array with Objects like: `[{id:1, name: "one"},{id:1, name: "one"}]` then you can use instead the index the object id (`:key="item.id"`).